# Pumping lemma, L={WW^R | W can be {1}+}

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, finite-state-machine

im trying to find out, if L is regular or not using pumping lemma.

I have L={WW^R | W can be {1}+}

So possible strings would be 11, 1111, 111111.
In every cases i have googled so far are examples with alphabet greater then 1, so there is understandable, that WW^R is not regular, but in this case, im lost.

Let's have a string w=111111, p=5 so

x=11
y=111
z=1

|xy|<=p
p>=1

xy^iz where i=0 i would have w=111 which is not WW^R and that would mean L is not regular.

But... Honesly, im not sure, whether am i doing it right or wrong.

Can some body help me out? And... Is that L realy NOT REGULAR?

Comment: What does {1}+ mean? Is this the [Kleene Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Kleene_plus) applied to the singleton set $\{1\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $L=\{1^{2n}\mid n\in\Bbb N,\, n>0\}$ which is *regular*. Can you find a finite state automata (with three states) that accepts exactly $L$?

Comment: Ty for answer. Why with 3 states? Am i missing something?. I can do expression like r=11(11)*... So it seems like regular, but I do t know, what am i doung wrong with the lemma (when i do the pumping lemma, it ends up with NON regular - so.. I am confused). Now i know that is regular, thank you. But... Dont know what i have been doing wrong in the lemma

Comment: Well, you need a 3rd state if the alphabet contains more symbols. You don't apply correctly the quantifiers in the pumping lemma. It also talks about some constants, and then that every word $w\in L$ can be split into $w=xyz$ such that ($|xy|\le N$ and) $y$ is pumpable. You found a wrong splitting, though there also exists a good one, e.g. $x=y=z=11$. (Note that the pumping corresponds to a repeated state in the automata during the procession of $w$.)

Answer (score 0):

The pumping lemma states that there **exists** a factorization $xyz$ that satisfies the pumping condition, not that **every** such factorization fulfills the lemma. The factorization you are looking at indeed does not fulfill the pumping condition.

In this case, any factorization with $y$ of an even length (and fulfilling the conditions of the lemma) will do. For example
$$x= \lambda, y=11, z = 1111$$ 
should do, if the lemma's formulation allows empty $x$, which it usually does.